# Xamarin SciChart in C#/Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin, scichart

I'm a beginner on Xamarin and SciChart. I've downloaded the SciChart package which I'd like to use in my application.

I've added the references SciChart.Android.Charting.dll, SciChart.Android.Core.dll, SciChart.Android.Data.dll and SciChart.Android.Drawing.dll.
Immediately after that when i try to run the application (without using the dll's) I got several build errors:

```
error: package com.scichart.charting.model.dataSeries does not exist extends 
com.scichart.charting.model.dataSeries.HIDataSeries
...
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue? What else do I have to do?

My second question is where I can find a xaml example on how to use the SciChart-package. All code examples I've found is code behind code but no xaml code to use the actual charts etc.

Comment: You need to add it via their private nuget channel as individually adding references will not work correctly. And those packages are Xamarin.Android|iOS based, not Xamarin.Forms based so you will need to embed them as native views within a Xamarin.Forms package : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt790186.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Next problem is that a get a reference error: "SciChart 5.1.0.11405 was restored using .NETFramework 4.6.1 instead of project target framework v2.0". Isn't Xamarin compatible with .Net 4.6, because it's installed but i cannot select any higher version than 2.0 in project properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe reference error which you mentioned is caused by referencing SciChart WPF DLLs.

Please take a look on [this tutorial](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/android/v2.x/webframe.html#Xamarin%20Tutorial%2001%20-%20Adding%20SciChart%20libraries%20as%20dependencies.html) which shows how to add SciChart Android DLLs from NuGet feed.

Hope this will help you!

*Disclosure: I am the lead developer on the SciChart Android team*